# Angular 5 AoT- Runtime Exceptions

Tags: angular, angular-aot

I am building an application with angular 5 CLI. When I build the application with dev environment it is working fine. But same code if I build with --prod and --aot flags, the application loads perfectly but I get some run-time exceptions which later causes the application to crash. I am not able the diagnose the issue as all the JavaScript files are minified and I don't have much knowledge of JavaScript and jQuery.Can someone help me in this?

Following exception I see in the console.
[image]

Comment: I would suggest to look every `toUpperCase` function in your app

Comment: Thanks @OmurbekKadyrbekov. But actually I am not using this method explicitly anywhere in the code.